# qemu openbsd network problems

Tags: networking, virtualbox, qemu, openbsd

hey I have troubles with internet in openbsd 6.6 (latest release) on qemu 4.2.0 (latest from brew) on macos 10.14.6 host.

Symptoms:

1. "ping google.com" returns "signature mismatch"!
2. "syspatch" or "pkg_add" are crashing with "ftp: SSL read error: read fail: error:06FFF064:digital envelop routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad decrypt"
3. "ftp" command works normal, downloads stuff from http and https without problems

Qemu conig:

`qemu-system-x86_64 -accel hvf -m 1024M -hda disk.qcow2 -boot c -nic user,model=virtio-net-pci`

Description:

I tried in qemu on hvf and tcg and with em0 and vio0 network devices. Problem persists. I tried the same configuration in virtualbox (hyper-v and virtio net) and there is no problem.

I also tried in qemu openbsd guest different clock/timezone settings, http/https and different mirrors for /etc/installurl. This doesn;t help. Problems seems to be with internet in general, not just ssl. However ftp over http works just fine.

Comment: It could be related to this https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/sbin/ping/ping.c#L1246

Answer (score 0):

For #1, the Qemu user-mode networking is munging the payload of your ping packets. OpenBSD sends both a timestamp (with a random offset from real system time) plus an MAC (message authentication code, not a MAC address). When the reply packet comes, it verifies the MAC to ensure the timestamp hasn't been altered in transit. In your case, it has, hence the error.

The best solution is to move to a tap network backend, which should fix the problem.

For #2, it's less clear what's going on without more details. Try changing from the user-mode networking first.